# Copy char* into char

Tags: c, debugging

I want to copy a variable type char* into variable type char.
When debugging , i occured an error : "Exception has occured" with the command strcpy.

How can i change the declaration of strcpy ? Any suggestions please .

```
typedef struct 
{
  int loadId; ///< ID de la charge
  long version; ///< Version de l'objet
  char loadCustomerId[CL_DSP_ID_LOCATION+1];
}DSP_Load;

DSP_Load donneesLoad;
char *loadCustomerID = (char*)json_string_value(obj);
strcpy(donneesLoad.loadCustomerId, loadCustomerID);
```

Comment: `donneesLoad.loadCustomerId` and `loadCustomerId` appear to be two completely different things. Also having two variables that differ by one letter case is downright devious.

Comment: Can you give more context as to what `donneesLoad` is?

Comment: @tadman: yes i edited the code , so DSP_load  is a strcuture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strcpy` function only stops copying when it encounters a null character in the source string. That means that if the source string is larger than the destination array, you will have a buffer overflow and invoke Undefined Behaviour.

A safer version is `strncpy`. Simply it may not null terminate the destination string if all positions are used. Here you could do:

```
strncpy(donneesLoad.loadCustomerId, loadCustomerID, CL_DSP_ID_LOCATION); // prevent buffer overflow
donneesLoad.loadCustomerId[CL_DSP_ID_LOCATION] = '\0';                   // ensure a terminating null
```

Comment: the prototype fo strncpy is :  char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n) , you should change the position of the lengh and the src

Comment: @Electrob: Oops, I should have read my own code... Thank you for the fix.

Comment: I didn't understand the second line in your code.

Comment: @Electrob: If `loadCustomerID` is longer than CL_DSP_ID_LOCATION, `strncpy` will copy exactly CL_DSP_ID_LOCATION bytes and `donneesLoad.loadCustomerId` could not be null terminated. The second line ensures that even in that case, `donneesLoad.loadCustomerId` will always be null terminated.

Comment: but the second line is wrong, it contains ") " Can you edited your code please.

Comment: @Electrob : Edited. I think it is time for me to have a coffee...